# Setup Keycloak automatic using REST API

Tags: docker, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I want to setup Keycloak for my Pipeline, this should be done automatically, I thought of manually pre configuring an realm in the webinterface of keycloak and then exporting this realm using this page:
[exporting page on keycloak image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKPua.png)

then i want to import it at every run of the pipeline so I get a fresh environment.

For importing my realm I used this endpoint:

`http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms`

[documented here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_realms_admin_resource)

when executing in postman, I get this error

`"error": "unknown_error"`

and in the console it says

`Script upload is disabled`

It looks like script uploads could be activated but according to the documentation [docu profiles](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#profiles) this feature is marked as deprecated. So I think this option would not be the way to go and future proof?

Maybe there is even another option that would be better for my usecase?

I am using Keycloak in a Docker Container quay.io/keycloak/keycloak - with the latest version currently version 15.0.1 of keycloak

Thank you for your time to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time I have found a solution that worked for me and maybe this is also helpful for others.

Some things to notice:

- I only need the import realm feature for development - for production it would work a little different.
- This is also for the Quarkus versions of Keycloak in older versions it also works different

Docker Compose:

```
services:
  keycloak:
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.1
      command: start-dev --import-realm
      volumes:
        - ./path/to/local/realm_export.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/realm.json:ro
```

more details about the import can be found here:
[Keycloak Import Export Documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/server/importExport)